# AspNet Core Razor View with PuppeteerSharp

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, puppeteer-sharp

Can we use PuppeteerSharp with Razor View. I want to send the HTML from Razor View inside AspNetCore app and get the output as PDF. Any references or code samples would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can inject the HTML using [SetContentAsync](https://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.Page.html#PuppeteerSharp_Page_SetContentAsync_System_String_PuppeteerSharp_NavigationOptions_) and then call [PdfAsync](https://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.Page.html#PuppeteerSharp_Page_PdfAsync_System_String_)

```cs
await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = false,
}))
using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
{
    await page.SetContentAsync("Hello World");
    await page.PdfAsync("test.pdf");
}
```

Comment: Thanks..If the page has reference to external JS or CSS files how can I load them or tell Puppeteer to load them.

Comment: Yes, but you have to be sure that a browser can access that resource. It can't be a relative url.

Answer (score 0):

According to [github](https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp#generate-pdf-files) you can generate PDF file like this

```
await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = false
});
var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
await page.GoToAsync("http://localhost/your/page");
Stream pdfStream = await page.PdfStreamAsync();
```