# A best Html to PDF converter in ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf-generation

I want to convert html to pdf in my website (ASP.NET Core 6.0), but I can't find the solution.
It should be created by specifing a url.

In ASP.NET MVC 5 era, I had used the library called Tuespeckin.

Is there any solution, which is free and elegant , that can work in ASP.NET Core 6.0?

Although following article was so helpful, it may a little obsolete.
[Can PDFSharp create Pdf file from a Html string in Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60342727/can-pdfsharp-create-pdf-file-from-a-html-string-in-net-core)

First answer mention SelectPDF, but I wish more modern methods, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Syncfusion` to convert html to pdf.

First, Install `Syncfusion.HtmlToPdfConverter.Net.Windows` NuGet package.

Then, Edit the corresponding method in the controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult ExportToPDF()
    {
        HtmlToPdfConverter htmlConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

        //Convert URL to PDF document
        PdfDocument document = htmlConverter.Convert("https://www.syncfusion.com");

        //Create memory stream
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        //Save the document
        document.Save(stream);

        return File(stream.ToArray(), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, "HTML-to-PDF.pdf");
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the namespace:

```
using Syncfusion.Pdf;
using Syncfusion.HtmlConverter;
```

Finally, Add the call in `Index.cshtml`:

```
@{
    Html.BeginForm("ExportToPDF", "Home", FormMethod.Post);
    {
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Convert HTML to PDF" style="width:250px;height:27px" />
        </div>
    }
    Html.EndForm();
}
```

You can change the URL Page you want to download in the controller method:

```
PdfDocument document = htmlConverter.Convert("Your Url");
```

For more details, you can refer to [this document](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/converting-html-to-pdf-in-asp-net-core).

**Update:**

Yes, it's not actually open source, you need to get a [license key](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/176736/created-with-a-trial-version-of-syncfusion-essential-pdf?reply=Sfg2Ja) to remove it (only 30 days free trial).

Free and effective first choice is actually SelectPDF.

If you really don't want to use it, you can choose the following two:

[PuppeteerSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55534593/aspnet-core-razor-view-with-puppeteersharp):
It's a headless chrome instance which can capture pdfs, and has a nice C# library (Puppeteer Sharp).

[jsPDF](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f8793014-5514-4c89-92b8-3df0bf79681a/how-to-pass-a-jspdf-output-to-post-action-via-ajax?forum=aspdotnetcore):
This is also a conversion tool used by open source.

Just my opinion, I think the experience of these two is not as good as SelectPDF. Maybe there are other free and up-to-date PDF converters, but I haven't found them and haven't used them.

Comment: Thanks, @Chen  I have also tried using Synfusion but there is a message ' Created with a trial version of Syncfusion Essential PDF' in head in the generated PDF document.
My environment is ASP.NET Core 6.0 and Synfusion 20.3.0.50.
When I inpremented same method to .NET Core 5.0 before, it did't appear. Synfusion version was 18.x in that time.

How about your environment?

Comment: Hi, @hiks, I updated my answer. You can just use it as a reference, hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you as always, @Chen.  I'm grateful to you for your help. I has decided to use SelectPDF.

Comment: Hi, @Chen. I have found a useful tips about Syncfusion. It has Community License for free and I have the eligibility to use it. I'm glad that I was able to make use of the information you described.

Comment: In community edition, we can generate pdf without trial message.